# Freeform Pro fields and MSM, fields not consistent across multi sites

Tags: solspace-freeform

FreeForm 4.2 
EE 2.8.1
MSM

Today I needed to create the first form for one of the sites on our EE with Multi-site. So I began by creating fields. I went to create a *First Name* field, but FreeForm told me the **field name** already existed and I needed to select another name. Which was a surprise to me since this was the first field and form I was creating for this site. I checked the fields list and it clearly wasn't showing. So I checked the other site and confirmed the **field name** was being already used. So I had to switch my field naming conventions to help differentiate. And I created all the fields needed for the form. But I didn't use a different convention for the **field label**.

Then I began to create the form, setting the *Form Type* to *Composer*. In the list of fields, I now have two *First Name* fields. The list uses the **field label**, so now I can't tell them apart. I have to edit one to check the **field name** so I select the field for this site and not the other site.

I suggest that you either let FreeForm share the fields across the multiple sites or create a better separation between the sites. And I lean towards the latter. And by better separation I think I should be able to reuse the **field labels**, **field names**, **form names** and **form labels** etc without worrying about names on other sites.

Comment: I know Solspace monitors EE SE but you might want to post this as a feature request on their site as they decide what features to prioritize based on voting there: http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions/forums/213788

Comment: Thank you for the advice. My first instinct is to post here but when I went to their support page, I copied this message as a bug report to Solspace a little after posting here. Hopeufully they process it and reply.

Answer (score 0):

Solspace replied with their support ticket. Here is what they wrote:

> Having all site's fields in Composer indeed complicates things if field labels are the same across multiple sites. This was mentioned by other users, and I added your voice to the bug report about this. Unfortunately we can't provide an ETA for bug fixes/feature additions.
>
> As for using the same field_shortnames in different sites, I don't know if Freeform's current data architecture can handle that, but I filed a feature request for it in any case :)

Answer (score 0):

Having your Freeform fields work across all MSM sites is doable. You just need to enable (check) the *"Show Data from All Sites"* setting in the Freeform **Preferences** tab in the EE CP. :)

All that said, there are a couple of bugs that are allowing you to experience the behaviour you're seeing. We have a new version of Freeform coming out in the next few days that will correct that (but the former part of this answer should still remain true and work for you now). :)

Comment: Thanks! Since I set up the duplicate fields, and am hoping Freeform soon has better separation between sites (so that I can use the same field_shortnames on different sites), I am not going to go back and change the configuration.